# GlassFish 3: HTTPS request on HTTP listener hangs

Tags: ssl, https, glassfish

I have a program that connects to a JSF application in GlassFish using HTTPS, but GlassFish is only configured for plain HTTP. That program tries HTTPS first and falls back to HTTP, if HTTPS does not work.

Using *ssldump* I can see that GlassFish 2.1 immediately sends a TCP FIN when receiving the HTTPS request, but GlassFish 3.1.2.2 just sits idle.

Here's what GlassFish 2.1 does:

> New TCP connection #1: localhost(53643) <-> localhost(8081)
>       1 1  0.0008 (0.0008)  C>S  Handshake
>             ClientHello
>               Version 3.1
>               cipher suites
>       ...
>       1    0.0106 (0.0098)  S>C  TCP FIN

Here is what GlassFish 3.1.2.2 does:

> New TCP connection #1: localhost(53388) <-> localhost(8081)
>       1 1  0.0005 (0.0005)  C>S  Handshake
>             ClientHello
>               Version 3.1
>               cipher suites
>       ...
>       1    59.9989 (59.9983)  C>S  TCP FIN

How can I make GlassFish 3.1.2.2 immediately close the connection (attempt)?

I used standard out of the box configurations for the HTTP listeners. There is no firewall in the picture. I ran both these tests on the same machine with the same client program, just with a different GlassFish each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a problem with the client's OpenSSL library being outdated. Everything worked fine after updating OpenSSL.